# Finding the convolution $a^n u[n]$ with $b^n u[n]$

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

Hi I'm trying to solve the problem when studying for an upcoming test. The given solution is $$y[n]= \frac{1}{b-a}(b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}) \quad \text{for } n\ge0 \ .$$ However, I'm not sure how to reach this point. We have to also verify using the z-transform. Any help would be appreciated so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it the hard way by writing out the individual formulas for the general convolution sum
\begin{align}
y[n] &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a[k]b[n-k]\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a[k]b[n-k] &\scriptstyle{\text{because }a[k]=0~\text{whenever } k < 0,}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n a[k]b[n-k] &\scriptstyle{\text{because }b[n-k]=0~\text{whenever } k > n,}
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{array}{rclcl}
y[0] &= &a[0]b[0] &= &1\\
&&&= &\displaystyle\frac{b^1-a^1}{b-a}\\
y[1] &= &a[0]b[1] + a[1]b[0] &= &b+a\\
&&&= &\displaystyle\frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a}\\
y[2] &= &a[0]b[2] + a[1]b[1] + a[2]b[0] &= &b^2 + ba +a^2\
&&&= &\displaystyle\frac{b^3-a^3}{b-a}\\
&&&= &\displaystyle\frac{b^3-a^3}{b-a}\\
\vdots &= &\ddots~~~\scriptstyle{\text{Hey, Ma! I think I see a pattern developing here}}\\
\\
y[n] &= &a[0]b[n] + a[1]b[n-1] + \cdots + a[n]b[0]
&= &b^n + b^{n-1}a + \cdots + ba^{n-1} + a^n\\
&&&= &\displaystyle\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}
\end{array}
if you can recall the formula for the sum of a geometric series.